# Youtube api video search Request contains an invalid argument

Tags: youtube-api

I am trying to search youtube videos as per here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

This is my request:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id,snippet&type=video&videoEmbeddable=true&channelId=UUUhFaUpnq31m6TNX2VKVSVA&maxResults=6&order=relevance&q=bmw&key=API_KEY

I am getting "Request contains an invalid argument."

It works if I remove channelId but this parameter is supported as per docs. I need to have this parameter because I want to narrow down search in channel.

Btw, this request works in their API panel and returns results:

curl 
'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&part=snippet&channelId=UCUhFaUpnq31m6TNX2VKVSVA&maxResults=6&order=relevance&q=bmw&type=video&videoEmbeddable=true&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' 
--header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' 
--header 'Accept: application/json' 
--compressed

Comment: Your request uses channel id UUUhFaUpnq31m6TNX2VKVSV  the curl one that works uses UCUhFaUpnq31m6TNX2VKVSVA.  Your request wont work without a valid channel id